# Jenkins P4 Plugin: p4sync failing to sync Unicode files

Tags: jenkins, unicode, jenkins-plugins, perforce, perforce-client-spec

I'm having trouble with using p4sync in a Jenkins build system.

Specifically, our P4 server is unicode-enabled. This is all fine and good, and when I call p4sync in my Jenkinsfile, I make sure to specify that the server is, in fact, a `utf8` (UTF-8 No BOM) server. However, when I actually sync, the sync appears to hitch when syncing files that are marked as type `unicode` in the depot, causing the sync (and build) to fail with the extremely unhelpful error message `ERROR: P4: Task Exception: com.perforce.p4java.exception.P4JavaException: com.perforce.p4java.exception.P4JavaException: hudson.AbortException: P4JAVA: Error(s): Unknown client error.` This issue only occurs when syncing through the Jenkins p4plugin, as well; I cannot replicate this behavior when syncing through the p4 CLI nor P4V.

I can manually go into the depot and change the filetype from `unicode` to `utf8` and that appears to fix the issue, but I would prefer not to have to manually resolve this issue in the depot whenever it comes up, or whenever someone happens to submit a unicode-enabled file with the wrong encoding.

Comment: This sounds like maybe the `P4CHARSET` is invalid -- I'm not sure how you'd set that within the context of Jenkins, but I'd expect it to be by roughly the same mechanism by which you set `P4PORT` etc.

Comment: That was my thought as well; however, the p4jenkins plugin specifies the charset in the construction of the workspace object itself, and I have it set to `utf8`, same as our Perforce server. Setting `P4CHARSET` on the build agent itself doesn't appear to make a difference

Comment: deleted comment, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing to resolve this was manually convert all files marked `unicode` in the depot to `utf8`, then set up a Perforce submission trigger to disallow submission of changelists containing files marked `unicode`. Thus, the depot is never in a state whereby the `p4sync` step fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the test.Sync and test.StreamingSync tests from here:
https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/joel_brown/p4java/JenkinsOps

See the README for instructions.
set/export P4CHARSET=utf8 before.

Hopefully that gives a better/meaningful exception.

Answer (score 0):

After updating a bunch of stuff (Perforce Server [v2015=>v2021], Jenkins [v? => v2.303.3], Jenkins P4 Plugin [v?=>v1.11.6], Java [JRE-8.?=> JDK-11.0.12]), we have the exact same problem. There seem to be some Unicode files that sync successfully, but a lot do not (the working example we found was submitted after the server update). The job is configured to use utf8 charset.

We ran the JenkinsOps test on the Jenkins workspace after the failed sync. This worked with no error IF we set the P4CHARSET environment variable to utf8. This did not work when we did not set the variable, or set it to winansi and we get a complex error message containing the “Unknown client error” string. P4 and P4V have basically the same behavior. P4/P4V in winansi mode returns the error message “Translation of file content failed near line 1 file C:\workspace\SomeExample.txt”. Again, everything works fine with JenkinsOps and p4/p4v if the utf8 mode is active.
All in all it looks to me like the Jenkins job does not apply the utf8 charset, although it is set in the job parameters.

Comment: @Steve: While this doesn't provide an answer, it does add extra details which may help future contributors answer the question. From [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _"Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on."_

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to

set P4CHARSET=utf8

before starting up the Jenkins process.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments of the original post, this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: This worked for us in our setup where we just run the master/built-in node with no slaves.  We have a startup script that calls set P4CHARSET and then starts up the jenkins war.